# jQuery get html content INSIDE div

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am loading content from a url div using jQuery load(). At the moment my code looks like this:

```
$('#content-slider').load(pageurl + '?rel=tab  #content-slider');
```

This basically goes to 'pageurl' and obtains `#content-slider` and loads it into the `#content-slider` on the current page.

The problem is I'm ending up with a div within a div with the same id:

```
<div id="content-slider">
    <div id="content-slider">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I obtain the html content INSIDE the div but not the div tags.

**UPDATE:** *Apologies if the question is not clear but for those that keep commenting that I shouldn't have duplicate ID... I know! The question is how to overcome this.*

Comment: IDs are Identifiers. Identifiers are unique so it's not good to use one identifier a second time

Comment: You could have use specific class names for your selector rather than IDs. Remember that elements can have more than one class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell `load` to get the *child* nodes of the content slider rather than the slider itself:

```
$('#content-slider').load(pageurl + '?rel=tab  #content-slider > *');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/egavuv/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/egavuv/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to T.J's answer you could also use `.parent`

```
 $("#content-slider").parent().load(pageurl + '?rel=tab  #content-slider');
```

[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/egavuv/3/) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/egavuv/3/edit)